# Prevent Screenshots in Android Application (Kotlin)

Tags: android, security, screenshot

I am trying to prevent screenshots inside the application. The answers from Google didn't help.

I've tried to set the flags as all other people answer but it simply doesn't work. I am still able to take screenshots while I set flags.

I set flags before setting the content view.
I use genymotion emulator.

The code

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
```

I expect to see the screenshot taken blurry or anyhow malformed because I have secure content which must not be seen by other person via screenshots.

Comment: this is kotlin so it is propert access

Comment: "I am still able to take screenshots" -- how are you doing this? "I use genymotion emulator" -- try it on hardware. Your users are not using Genymotion. `FLAG_SECURE` definitely works, assuming that the device manufacturer (or ROM developer) did not screw anything up. "I have secure content which must not be seen by other person via screenshots" -- bear in mind that the user has other ways of sharing your content, such as by taking a photo of the device screen.

Comment: I take screenshots via genymotion. Wha'ts the point of using hardware if average user knows about genymotion and it can be more comfortable for such user just to use emulator instead  of the hard drive. I know that there are plenty ways and I am trying to prevent the ones which can be under my control

Comment: I just tried exact same thing via official Android Emulator from Google...same!

Comment: I don't know how you say about "definitely" works because I've just tried and it doesn't

Comment: "I take screenshots via genymotion" -- that did not answer my question. "if average user knows about genymotion and it can be more comfortable for such user just to use emulator instead of the hard drive" -- well, with an emulator, they can always take a screenshot by using their desktop OS. There is no defense against that. "I don't know how you say about "definitely" works because I've just tried and it doesn't " -- what hardware did you try?

Comment: For example, I tried your code in a Pixel 2 running Android 9.0, and when I try to take a screenshot using the power button, I get a notification saying that my taking screenshots isn't allowed by my app. If I try taking a screenshot with a developer tool, such as Android Studio, I get an error.

Comment: correct. Can confirm that it works on hardware